# NSDictionary returning me empty string in push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification

here is my payload

```
{
    aps =     {
        ImageURL = "http://i.forbesimg.com/media/lists/people/cristiano-ronaldo_416x416.jpg";
        alert = testing;
    };
}
```

and here is my code

```
NSDictionary *aps = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[launchOptions objectForKey:@"aps"]];
NSString *text = [aps objectForKey:@"alert"];
NSString *imageUrl = [aps objectForKey:@"ImageURL"];
```

this code is working in didRecievePushNotification but not in didFinishLaunching

Comment: Are you sure that your launchOptions dictionary is the same when called from both methods? Try logging launchOptions and comparing the output.

Comment: Actually the issue in when i kill the app and send push notification in that time there is no debugger with it

Answer (score 1):

That code should work, although it's overly complex and inefficient. There's no reason to create a new dictionary with the contents of your `launchOptions` dictionary.

Simply say

```
NSString *text = ((NSDictionary*)launchOptions[@"aps"])[@"alert"];
NSString *imageURL = ((NSDictionary*)launchOptions[@"aps"])[@"ImageURL"];
```

Or

```
NSDictionary *aps = (NSDictionary*)launchOptions[@"aps"];
NSString *text = aps[@"alert"];
NSString *imageURL = aps[@["ImageURL"];
```

Comment: Note that in the second option above, I don't alloc/init a new dictionary; I simply extract the value of the key "aps" and cast it to the correct type.

Comment: So log `launchOptions`, `fps`, `text`, and `imageURL`.